# drf performing serializer validations on default database

Tags: python, validation, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have these DB configs in my `settings.py`:

```
"default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": os.environ["DB_NAME"],
        "USER": os.environ["DB_USER"],
        "PASSWORD": os.environ["DB_PASS"],
        "HOST": os.environ["DB_SERVICE"],
        "PORT": os.environ["DB_PORT"],
    },
    "external": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": os.environ["DB_NAME_EXTERNAL"],
        "USER": os.environ["DB_USER_EXTERNAL"],
        "PASSWORD": os.environ["DB_PASS_EXTERNAL"],
        "HOST": os.environ["DB_SERVICE_EXTERNAL"],
        "PORT": os.environ["DB_PORT_EXTERNAL"],
    }
```

And I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    """Model Class for Solution Model"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

And a serializer for the model defined above:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def query(self, **kwargs):
        organization = self.context['request'].user.token['organization']
        return MyModel.objects.using(organization).all()

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        organization = self.context['request'].user.token['organization']

        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = MyModel.objects.using(organization).create(**self.validated_data)
        else:
            self.instance = MyModel.objects.using(organization).filter(id=self.instance.id).update(**self.validated_data)

        return self.instance

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have overwritten my serializer's `save` method to adhere with multiple DBs I'm using. This is working fine as long as my `serializer.is_valid()` returns true in my viewsets. But when I try to create a new object in *external* DB with name that is already there in *default* DB, it throws validation error. This should not happen as these are two different DBs. I suspect that `serializer.is_valid` method is always checking the default DB and I don't know how to make this check external DB.